# Auto-import missing package prefix

Tags: neovim, pyright

Currently, I have quite a solid setup with my neovim, and I'm pretty happy so far, there is just one thing annoying me which is the auto-import feature suggested by the nvim-cmp

I have a structure like

```
src/
    models/
           modelA.py
```

When I'm using a class reference inside the modelA, the auto-import tool suggests the import like...

```
from models.modelA import Potatoes
```

And I would expect something like

```
from src.models.ModelA import Potatoes
```

I've been reading the documentation but nothing really effective for this issue atm.